# Error when creating a stack with protocol type conforming to CustomStringConvertible in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I want to use a generic stack in my code where the generic type must conform to the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol.I have a protocol that conforms to `CustomStringConvertible` and I would like to create a stack of this protocol type. However, when I try to do this, I get an error. To keep things simple, I have illustrated the problem below with protocol P and struct S which adopts protocol P.

The code below does not compile:

```
struct Stack<E: CustomStringConvertible> {
    var items = [E]()
    mutating func push(_ item: E) { items.append(item) }
    mutating func pop() -> E { return items.removeLast() }
}

protocol P: CustomStringConvertible {}

struct S: P {
    var description: String { return "Struct S" }
}

var protocolStack = Stack<P>()    // error
protocolStack.push(S())
print(protocolStack.pop().description)
```

It appears the error is caused by the requirement that the generic type should conform to `CustomStringConvertible`. If I remove this requirement, the code compiles and runs fine, as shown below:

```
struct Stack<E> {
    var items = [E]()
    mutating func push(_ item: E) { items.append(item) }
    mutating func pop() -> E { return items.removeLast() }
}

protocol P {
    var description: String { get }
}

struct S: P {
    var description: String { return "Struct S" }
}

var protocolStack = Stack<P>()
protocolStack.push(S())
print(protocolStack.pop().description)    // prints: Struct S
```

-- UPDATED --

Just discovered the code in the first panel works when the `CustomStringConvertible` conformance requirement is introduced through an extension of struct Stack.

```
struct Stack<E> {
    var items = [E]()
    mutating func push(_ item: E) { items.append(item) }
    mutating func pop() -> E { return items.removeLast() }
}

extension Stack where E: CustomStringConvertible {}

protocol P: CustomStringConvertible {}

struct S: P {
    var description: String { return "Struct S" }
}

var protocolStack = Stack<P>()
protocolStack.push(S())
print(protocolStack.pop().description)   // prints: Struct S
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself: A protocol does not conform to itself.

Comment: @MartinR, I have seen the other question and its accepted answer. But, unless I am missing something, my problem seems a bit different. My code does compile if I remove the condition that the Element generic type should conform to CustomStringConvertible. Would appreciate if someone could show how the box-unbox solution proposed in the other question will solve my issue.

Comment: I have edited my question to illustrate the problem more clearly.

Comment: @MartinR just updated my original post. Got the code to work by adding the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol conformance requirement via an extension of struct Stack.